# Route traffic through VPN for specific destinations

Tags: router, vpn

I would like to route some requests through a VPN while some others would go through a "normal" route. For instance, all requests to website *.xxxx.com, would get routed through the VPN, but all others would go through my ISP normal route.

There are some browser extensions, which can do that, but I would prefer to do that at the router's level, so that all devices in the house would benefit from it.

I can't find help on this topic, but maybe I don't have the correct english name for it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the term you are looking for is "split tunneling". 
Whether or not it can be implemented on your router though, is entirely dependent on the router and its firmware's capability.